# How to distinguish between the screen going off and the activity being sent in background in android

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app which speaks and listens to the user. Basically an app which allows placing phone calls without having to look or touch the device (believe it or not I didn't find any in the market!).
The point here is that I want:

- to keep running when the screen goes off
- to stop running when the user switches to another activity

And I don't see an easy way to understand this.
I've already looked into this: [How to stop a background thread when the screen in android device goes off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180979/how-to-stop-a-background-thread-when-the-screen-in-android-device-goes-off)

but the events are being fired in the wrong order (from my logs):

- onPause: screen status UNKNOWN
- onStop: screen status UNKNOWN
- screen event: OFF

  ```
  public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
          // do whatever you need to do here
          wasScreenOn = ScreenStatus.OFF;
          Log.d(TAG,"screen event OFF");
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
          // and do whatever you need to do here
          wasScreenOn = ScreenStatus.ON;
          Log.d(TAG,"screen event ON");
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: I doubt that Screen on off and activity life-cycle methods run in sync with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **PowerManager** as shown in this post, hope it helps. Seems like what you needed,

[how to check screen on/off status in onStop()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350258/how-to-check-screen-on-off-status-in-onstop)

Comment: sorry Android Killer: this will _not_ solve my problem. onStop() gets called both if the user navigates away from the app and if the screen goes blank. As described I'm actually asking how to distinguish the two things

Comment: @SimoneAvogadro Edited the answer, please check. This can be done withour BroadcastReceiver i think.

Comment: this is now exactly what I needed. On my reference device it does exactly what I needed. Thanks